# xl2tpd redial doesn't work

Tags: vpn, xl2tpd

`/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf`:

```
redial = yes
redial timeout = 1
autodial = yes
```

Version of `xl2tpd` default, latest Ubuntu 14.04 ( Trusty ):

```
xl2tpd  1.3.6+dfsg-1 amd64  layer 2 tunneling protocol implementation
```

I'm always pinging some host like Google, default DNS - 8.8.8.8.

From time to time I'm losing the connection, ping is silent and `xl2tpd` doesn't reconnect.

Seems like `xl2tpd` doesn't know that the connection is broken.

Is there any option to keep an internet connection alive, to keep `xl2tpd` redial automatically?

Now, I use a raw and dirty bash script wrapper around ping and also `service xl2tpd restart` to redial `xl2tpd`.

Is there a more program (`xl2tpd`) friendly way?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try. I would set the max redial to a high number so that it will attempt to redial for more tries. Perhaps it's exhausting redial attempts and no longer trying. Also I'd set the `redial timeout` to something like 2.

*excerpt from the xl2tpd man page*

- redial - If set to yes, xl2tpd will attempts to redial if the call get disconected.
- redial timeout - Wait X seconds before redial. The redial option must be set to yes to use this option.
- max redial - Will give up redial tries after X attempts.

Also you might want to take a look at this example script here in this Gist titled: [vpn_dorm.sh](https://gist.github.com/Hexcles/6562821). It might shed some light on alternatives.

Comment: Great. I'm on the way. Say, 7 days without hand re-connections, and your answer - is my.

Comment: @unixlinuxuser - sorry didn't understand your comment.